# TSQL counting '1' in a string position, by positions

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, count, aggregate

There are fields for categories like that:

"101011111000000101010011000101..." every position in this strings represents a certain category if set to "1".
So "1" means set and "0" means not set.
I would like to count the categories with the highest number of "1" and order them descending.

My current solution is like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Interests], 1, 1)) AS xcount, 1 AS ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Interests], 1, 1) = '1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Interests], 2, 1)) AS xcount, 2 AS ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Interests], 2, 1) = '1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Interests], 3, 1)) AS xcount, 3 AS ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Interests], 3, 1) = '1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Interests], 4, 1)) AS xcount, 4 AS ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Interests], 4, 1) = '1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING([Interests], 5, 1)) AS xcount, 5 AS ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Interests], 5, 1) = '1'
ORDER BY xcount DESC
```

Is there a better or faster way to count those categories?

Comment: How many categroy you have? All `Interests` are same length?

Comment: The number of categories depnends on the field length. It is always the same for all records in that table. But there may be other fields with a differnt length...but this method of selecting should work for all lengths.

Comment: You need dynamic query to get all categories

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([Interests], _ID.ID, 1) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS xcount, _ID.ID
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts], (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS _ID(ID)
GROUP BY _ID.ID
ORDER BY xcount DESC
```

For more categories just increase _ID sequence.

Comment: It doesn't work. SQL Server sais that ID is a "Ambiguous column name".

Comment: Maybe your Contacts table contains ID column? Then replace in my solution "ID" by any other name.

Comment: @Sergey Tally table can be helpful `declare @n int = (SELECT TOP(1) len([Interests]) FROM [db1].[dbo].[Contacts]); ...(SELECT TOP(@n) N as ID FROM Tally ORDER BY N) AS _ID...`

Answer (score 1):

This will count number of '1' in a string consisting of 0 and 1

```
declare @s varchar(100) ='101011111000000101010011000101';
select cnt = len(@s) - len(replace(@s,'0',''))
```

Comment: No, that's not what i want to do.
I want to count position 1 of the string over all records if the position contains '1' and repat this for a positions.